# Can someone please explain "Readdir" and "Open" wrapper methods

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang. Can someone please explain, how "Readdir" and "Open" wrapper methods are working?

This example is from Golang documentation.
https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#example-FileServer-DotFileHiding

More specifically, in the "Readdir" method, the statement `files, err := f.File.Readdir(n)` has n int value but from where it's passed and how it is working. "Readdir" method isn't called anywhere in the program.

Similarly in "Open" wrapper `file, err := fsys.FileSystem.Open(name)`

```
package main

import (
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

// containsDotFile reports whether name contains a path element starting with a period.
// The name is assumed to be a delimited by forward slashes, as guaranteed
// by the http.FileSystem interface.
func containsDotFile(name string) bool {
    parts := strings.Split(name, "/")
    for _, part := range parts {
        if strings.HasPrefix(part, ".") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// dotFileHidingFile is the http.File use in dotFileHidingFileSystem.
// It is used to wrap the Readdir method of http.File so that we can
// remove files and directories that start with a period from its output.
type dotFileHidingFile struct {
    http.File
}
f
// Readdir is a wrapper around the Readdir method of the embedded File
// that filters out all files that start with a period in their name.
func (f dotFileHidingFile) Readdir(n int) (fis []fs.FileInfo, err error) {
    files, err := f.File.Readdir(n)
    for _, file := range files { // Filters out the dot files
        if !strings.HasPrefix(file.Name(), ".") {
            fis = append(fis, file)
        }
    }
    return
}

// dotFileHidingFileSystem is an http.FileSystem that hides
// hidden "dot files" from being served.
type dotFileHidingFileSystem struct {
    http.FileSystem
}

// Open is a wrapper around the Open method of the embedded FileSystem
// that serves a 403 permission error when name has a file or directory
// with whose name starts with a period in its path.
func (fsys dotFileHidingFileSystem) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    if containsDotFile(name) { // If dot file, return 403 response
        return nil, fs.ErrPermission
    }

    file, err := fsys.FileSystem.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return dotFileHidingFile{file}, err
}

func main() {
    fsys := dotFileHidingFileSystem{http.Dir(".")}
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(fsys))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotFileHidingFileSystem type wraps an [http.FileSystem](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileSystem) and is itself an http.FileSystem.

The dotFileHidingFile type wraps an [http.File](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#File) and is itself an http.File.

Because these two struct types [embed](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding) the wrapped value, all of the methods on the wrapped value are promoted to methods on the wrapper type unless the wrapper type itself implements the method. Read the [Effective Go section on embedding](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding) if you are not familiar with the embedding concept.

The net/http [FileServer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer) calls the methods on the http.FileSystem and http.File interfaces.

The  [file server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer) calls the file system [Open](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileSystem.Open) method to open a file. The dotFileHidingFileSystem implementation of that method calls through to the wrapped file system to open the file and returns a dotFileHidingFile wrapper around that file.

If the file is a directory, the [file server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer) calls the file [Readdir](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#File.Readdir) method to get a listing of the files in the directory. The file server specifies the value of `n`.   The dotFileHidingFile implementation of the Readdir method calls through the the wrapped file Readdir method and filters dot files out of the result.

See the [ReadDirFile](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#ReadDirFile) documentation for documentation on the `n` argument to Readdir.